# How to connect Symfony to firebird database?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, firebird, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I'm trying to connect these two, but there is no information about it in here, does anyone have working example?

Comment: did you tried to ask the developers?  http://www.doctrine-project.org/community.html   "Symfony Framework doesn't integrate any component to work with databases, it provides tight integration with a third-party library called Doctrine." https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html the SQLite example makes me think of http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-firebird.php

Answer (score 3):

Symfony is agnostic of your persistence system. You can use PDO directly to connect to your Firebird database. Create the appropriates services using the Dependency Injection component to do so.

Alternatively, there is the Doctrine ORM. This library is often used with Symfony because it is installed with the Symfony Standard Edition. Doctrine doesn't support Firebird yet. However, there is a pending Pull Request adding support for it: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/838

You may try this fork for your project (at your own risk, it's very experimental) and help to finish the Pull Request to get it merged in the upstream project.

Comment: maybe  do you know a PHP framework that works with Firebird?

Comment: 1) http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-firebird.php
2) http://php.net/manual/en/book.ibase.php